IBSO in KerrGeodesics Paclet
Is there someone who knows the physical meaning of IBSO in KerrGeodesics Paclet?
IBSO (Innermost Bound Spherical Orbit)
Since I didn't find any physical meaning for it. While I found a lot about IBCO (Innermost Bound Circular Orbit)  it doesn't have any mention in the paclet.
Are they the same?

Since this seems to be a third party package, please add the link for the paclet to your question so we can check it easier.

https://bhptoolkit.org/KerrGeodesics/

Please add it to the body of question.

I feel this is more of a Physics question rather than Mathematica one ...

…OK, OP indeed asked in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/836472/18778 @Domen

If you cross-post a question, please provide the link(s) to other site(s) to avoid possible  repetitive work.

An innermost bound spherical orbit (IBSO) is a spherical orbit with specific energy equal to one.
